# How to get data from the current row in INSTEAD OF trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-delete

For example, we have a table named 'Names':

```
 id  |  name
-----+------
 1   |  Mary
 2   |  Sue
 3   |  John
```

and this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_insofdel
ON Names 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- here I need to get some data from the current row
END
```

and then I call

```
DELETE FROM Names 
WHERE id = 1
```

How can I get Mary's (id == 1) name in the trigger?

What is going on with the 'deleted' table in this case?

Comment: There is no "current row" in delete/update etc. triggers; `deleted` returns all rows in one query batch. If you happen to delete one row, it will return that one row. You should give details of what you want the trigger to do so we can see if it's feasible.

Comment: 'INSTEAD OF triggers cause their source DML operation to skip and they just execute the code provided inside them. Actual insert, delete or update operation do not occur at all. However they have their associated inserted and deleted tables simulating the DML operation.' - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1804/using-instead-of-triggers-in-sql-server-for-dml-operations/

Comment: `select name from deleted;` will return all of the names being deleted. Tip: If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row in the trigger then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017#using-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables-in-instead-of-triggers) does explain but it isn't laid out very clearly.

In a trigger, SQL server automatically makes 2 special in-memory tables available to you:

- `inserted`: the data which was added to the table (for insert and update statements)
- `deleted`: the data which was removed from the table (for update and delete statements)

They have the same columns as the actual table, but are completely read-only - you cannot add columns or indexes to them or change the data inside them.

So in your example, to get the name of the person being removed, you can do the following inside the trigger:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100);
SELECT @name = name from deleted;
```

**Important note**

Be aware tho that if multiple rows were deleted from the table, then `deleted` will contain multiple rows - the trigger is not called individually once for each row.